# Comparar valor de uma coluna com o checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando comparar o valor de uma coluna de uma `table`, para que dependendo do que for selecionado, mostrar ou esconder o campo, cheguei neste código:

```
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            console.log(td);
            debugger;
            if (td == $('#Produtos').prop("checked",true)) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
```

Porém não está filtrando, como corrigir? 
no `console.log(td)` está aparecendo assim `<td>True</td>` conforme cada linha, será que estou pegando errado o valor?

Comment: Tenta fazer o seguinte, `var tbBoolean = $(td).text() == "True" ? true : false;` esse codigo checa se o texto dentro da td esta igual `"True"`, ai voce pode checar o `tdBoolean == $('#Produtos').prop("checked")`.   Detalhe: fazendo isso aqui `$('#Produtos').prop("checked",true)` voce esta marcando o checkbox

Comment: @IcaroMartins quando faço isso, ele me retorna o seguinte erro: tdBoolean is not defined

Comment: Voce tem que colcocar esta linha primeiro, logo depois do console.log.
`var tbBoolean = $(td).text() == "True" ? true : false;`

Comment: Eu fiz isso, ele retornou erro nesta linha `if (tbBoolean == $('#Produtos').prop("checked")) {`

Comment: eu coloquei por engando **td**Boolean e depois **tb**Boolean, e so transformar todos para `tdBoolean`

Comment: Deu certinho, se quiser lançar a resposta, eu vou marcar pra você, obrigado. @IcaroMartins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após conversamos pelos comentários da pergunta conseguimos chegar a seguinte solução =)

```
// Criar uma var boolean
var tdBoolean = $(td).text() == "True" ? true : false;

// modificar a checagem para 
if( tdBoolean == $('#Produtos').prop("checked") )
// if (td == $('#Produtos').prop("checked",true))
// isso porque o $('#Produtos').prop("checked",true)
// estava marcando o checkbox
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
            console.log(td);
            debugger;

            var valorTd = (td == "True" ? true : false);

            if (valorTd  == $('#Produtos').is(":checked")) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
```

Comment: Não resolveu. Ele não compara os valores